# Automatically deploy when configMap changes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

Does anyone know how to get a Kubernetes deployment to automatically update when a configMap is changed?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is nothing built in for this. You used the `helm` tag, so with Helm you do this by setting a checksum of the rendered configmap (or secret, same issue there) as an annotation in the pod template. This means that changing the configmap results in a (meaningless) change to the pod template, which triggers a rolling update.

Comment: This appears to be the only solution. 
I just need to figure out how to pass the checksum in.

Comment: Docs got you covered, https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments :)

Comment: I've tried this unfortunately.
 
I get a "rendering template has a nested reference name: xyz.chart: unable to execute template" error.

Answer (score 3):

Consider reloader, a kubernetes controller, that watches changes to configmaps and secrets and will trigger a deployment when there is any change --> https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @coderanger, by default Kubernetes doesn't provide anything like this by default.

Consider using kapp. kapp has the concept of ([versioned](https://carvel.dev/kapp/docs/develop/diff/#versioned-resources)) resources. You can mark the ConfigMap as a versioned resource. After that, anytime this configmap will be updated, all the K8s resources referring this ConfigMap will be updated as well.