# How to automatically roll a CronJob on ConfigMap change

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When my ConfigMap changes, I'd like my CronJob to restart.

There's a trick in Helm to make this happen for Deployments using an annotation that contains the SHA of the ConfigMap (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61469357/2223706) or [here](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments)).

This works for my Deployment, doing `kubectl get deployments` show the AGE is just a couple minutes.

But not my CronJob, doing `kubectl get cronjobs`, the "AGE" is still hours old implying they haven't restarted.

Answer (score 2):

So, it turns out CronJobs don't need to be restarted when the ConfigMap changes anyway.  Everytime a Job is created, the Pod that spins up to execute the Job seems to use the latest ConfigMap values anyway.

Comment: yea. that's how it's works with configmap, secret both if you are using those with cronjob with deployment also configmap get auto-updated if you have mounted it. Extra if you would like to Read more : https://faun.pub/update-configmap-without-restarting-pod-56801dce3388